# Dynamically add form fields and populate

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamic, field

I'm creating a form where a user can enter their address history, when they land on the page they will be able to enter their postcode which will search postcode anywhere and select their address from the results which will then populate the following `hidden` fields - house_name, address1, town and county.

They will then have the ability to add as many other addresses as they wish until they have completed 5 years address history.

Is the best way to give the fields an array for their name e.g postcode[], house_name[], address1[], town[] and county[] with the additional addresses the same or to give them all unique names e.g postcode_1, house_name_1 etc then the next address postcode_2, house_name_2 etc?

Also, how would I get the postcode value from each for me to use to lookup postcode anywhere?

Comment: Could you explain what do you exactly mean by "how would I get the postcode value from each for me to use to lookup postcode anywhere?"

Comment: If each address has postcode[], how would I populate the applicable house_name[], address1[] etc? Would each have a unique id so postcode would have id="postcode1" and this would populate id="house_name1", id="address11" etc?

Comment: What I've done so far is when landing on the form you are presented with a postcode, house_name, address 1, town and county. These have input names postcode[], house_name[], address1[], town[] and county[] but have unique id's - postcode_1, house_name_1, town_1 and county_1. There is then the option to add multiple addresses so when the user clicks 'Add', new postcode, house name, address 1, town and county fields will be added to the form with the same name as above e.g postcode[], house_name[] etc but the id will be incremented e.g postcode_2, house_name_2, postcode_3, house_name_3 etc

Comment: Now when a user enters their postcode in the relevant postcode input field, I'm thinking of using the id of the field e.g postcode_1, postcode_2 etc to then populate the other applicable address fields e.g house_name_1, town_1, county_1 and if a user enters their postcode in the next postcode field (postcode_2) then house_name_2, town_2, county_1 etc will be populated. Does this make sense? Is there a way of populating the applicable fields without giving each field an ID? Possibly using $this in jquery to match the relevant fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you mean it would probably be best to store it in a 2 dimensional array:

for example:

```
item["1056BK"]["house_name"]
item["1056BK"]["town"]
item["1056BK"]["address"]
item["1056BK"]["country"]

item["3021BX"]["house_name"]
item["3021BX"]["town"]
item["3021BX"]["address"]
item["3021BX"]["country"]
```

That way you can easily loop over each item and put it in the db.

PS, this would be prefered:

```
item["0"]["postcode"]
item["0"]["house_name"]
item["0"]["town"]
item["0"]["address"]
item["0"]["country"]

item["1"]["postcode"]
item["1"]["house_name"]
item["1"]["town"]
item["1"]["address"]
item["1"]["country"]
```

Comment: thanks, so use actual numbers to uniquely identify the fields rather than simply postcode[], house_name[], town[] etc for each set of address fields?

Comment: Yes :) One array and all your data sorted nicely into rows